# OnTabEnter and <apex:ActionFunction>

Tags: apex

If the following is my code, what references what? I am trying to get a better idea of how this works. Does the ontabenter reference to the actionFunction name of the action?

```
<apex:actionFunction name="onClick" action="{!onClick}"/>
<apx:tab label="test" name="test" id="onClick" ontabenter="onClick()">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the first line you are making a local javascript function (name="onClick") to an apex function (action="{!onClick}") which is also called a binding.

On the second line, you are saying that when you go into a tab (ontabenter) call a javascript function ("onClick()").

[on tab enter] => javascript:onClick => apex:onClick()

Comment: @KushPatel this sort of confusion is why I prefer to keep the action name distinct from the JavaScript name. It makes the code easier to follow.